# GHCi freezes if I try to run a simple binTree

Tags: haskell

I started to learn Haskell as a new language just because I can. As a practice I tried to code a simple BinTree but I'm running in a quite infuriating error.

This is the sourcecode I'm having trouble with:

```
data Tree = Node Tree Int Tree
    | Empty
    deriving (Eq,Show)
    
addNode :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
addNode Empty a = Node Empty a Empty
addNode (Node left a right) b   | a > b = Node (addNode left b) a right
                                | a < b = Node left a (addNode right b)
                                | otherwise = Node left b right
```

Note: I tried running the code with `GHC 8.10.7` and `GHC 9.2.1` but to no avail.

The Problem happens as I'm trying to run `addNode` on an Empty binTree `test`.
Creating the empty binTree with  `test = Empty` and checking it with just `test` works out fine and gives me `Empty` as an result, but if I then try to add a node to test with `test = addNode test <Int>` and try to show me the result of `test` nothing happens. The compiler is trying to run the code, but it just freezes and I have to reopen PowerShell.

If it helps, this is my current setup:

`GHC 9.2.1 | 8.10.7`
`cabal 3.6.2.0`
`HLS 1.5.1`
`Stack 2.7.3`
`OS Win10`

Comment: By running `test = addNode test 5`, you weel keep adding `5` for an infinite amount of times.

Comment: But why? Through pattern matching Haskell should prefer `addNode Empty 5` which only gives back the new binTree `Node Empty 5 Empty` to prevent an infinite recursion, since I'm giving it a BinTree of the type `Empty` as start.

Comment: no, you can for example make an infinite list of `1`s with `foo = 1 : foo`. Note that `foo` is here more locally scoped than any `foo` that you may have defined in an outer scope. You can for example also make infinite trees, etc. If you turn on some warnings, the Haskell compiler (and ghci) will warn when you use the same variable (also when you use it as a more locally scoped one).

Comment: Outside `ghci`, you can not use two variables in the same scope. `ghci` makes an exception and impliclty adds `let` to each statement where you define a variable, and thus each time defines a smaller scope.

Comment: For future reference, in most ordinary cases where a computation gets stuck in GHCi, you can use Ctrl+C (or also Ctrl+Break iirc) to interrupt it and return to the prompt, instead of having to restart GHCi or the shell/console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By running `test = addNode test 5`, you weel keep adding `5` for an infinite amount of times. It does not take the "old" `test`. In Haskell a variable is always immutable, if you use `test` in the "body" of the definition, then it will use the variable you are defining. It works thus as a [*recursive* let statement [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression#Description).

Here it thus means that you define `test` as:

> let `test` be the result of adding *<Int>* to `test`.

and this will thus result in trying to add that integer value for an infinite amount of times, since it means `test` is adding <Int> to a tree that has add <Int> that has added <Int> that …

You can define a new variable and use the old tree with:

```
test2 = addNode test 5
```